# Bootstrap Gridview alignment mixed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Based on Bootstarp Gridview the sum of set of the columns must be equal to 12 for proper alignment and display.

Looking at the code bellow, the **col-xs-6** total are 18, but this display a proper alignment.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

I want someone to explain this to me.

NB: for me this sould be set as:

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common misconception that the columns must be equal to 12. There is nothing wrong with using more than 12, and in fact the Bootstrap docs state:

> "If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of
>   extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line"

There are also examples in the docs that demonstrate why this "column wrapping" in necessary: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping

[Read this article](http://blog.codeply.com/2015/06/24/when-to-use-bootstraps-row-class/). The only time you don't want to exceed 12 units is when nesting columns.

Comment: my concern is why in this case case the columns are not wrap to a new line with col-xs-6 that gives 18 ??

Comment: the last col does wrap to a new line on smallest (xs) screens: http://www.codeply.com/go/TbrKsyphQB

Answer (score 1):

Because your screen size is not in XS range and browser is rendering for "col-md-4"

It will wrap on screen size less than 992px (width)